# PHP - foreach не меняет изначальный массив

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

После перебора изначальный массив `$orders` не изменяется.

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    foreach ($cart as $cartItem) {
        if ($order['session_id'] == $cartItem['session_id']) {
            $order['items'] = [];
            array_push($order['items'], $cartItem['good_id'], $cartItem['good_count']);
        }
    }
}
```

Может это как-то связано с вложенностью циклов?

Comment: напиши с передачей по ссылке foreach ($orders as &$order) пример https://onlinegdb.com/rkxC47sPu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что в момент перебора массива foreach PHP копирует объект order в каждом цикле, а посему нельзя просто взять и изменить значение для него. Можно действительно перебирать массив по ссылки как было уже сказано, но также можно непосредственно заносить изменения в изначальный массив как-то так:

```
// вариант 1 - изменяем изначальный массив
foreach ($orders as $key => $order) {
  $orders[$key]['items'] =  []; 
}

// вариант 2 - используем перебор по ссылке
foreach ($orders as &$order) {
  $order['items'] =  []; 
}
```

Во втором варианте не происходит копирование объекта, а используется ссылка на объект, который находится в массиве.

Answer (score 3):

В вашем случае нужно использовать передачу по ссылке (`as &$order`):

```
foreach ($orders as &$order) {
    foreach ($cart as $cartItem) {
        if ($order['session_id'] == $cartItem['session_id']) {
            $order['items'] = [];
            array_push($order['items'], $cartItem['good_id'], $cartItem['good_count']);
        }
    }
}
```

https://php.net/language.references.pass